# BackgroundSubtractorMOG constructor values

Tags: java, opencv

I was trying to create a motion detection application, but I'm a little confused with BackgroundSubtractorMOG constructor values. I know what they refer to (lenght of the history, number of gaussian mixtures and background ratio), but I don't know how the algorithm changes when I change those values. For example:

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG bg = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG(15,3,0);
bg.apply(webcam_image, foreground);
```

How do those values change the function?

Answer (score 0):

The class discriminates between foreground and background pixels by building and maintaining a model of the background. Any pixel which does not fit this model is then deemed to be foreground.

and also studying this essay :
 KadewTraKuPong and R. Bowden. An improved adaptive background mixture model for real-time tracking with shadow detection. Proc. 2nd European Workshop on Advanced Video-Based Surveillance Systems, 2001
may help you to understand it better